# Why is the _replace method of Python namedtuple classes protected?

Tags: python, coding-style, inheritance

In the section [Method Names and Instance Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables), the Python Style Guide (aka PEP 0008) says, "Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables." Why then, does the `_replace` method on `namedtuple` have a leading underscore? `namedtuple` classes themselves do not invoke `_replace` at all, and meanwhile the existence of `_replace` is advertised in the docstring for `namedtuple()` (see [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/collections/__init__.py), for example).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the `namedtuple` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), it says:

> Any valid Python identifier may be used for a fieldname except for names starting with an underscore. Valid identifiers consist of letters, digits, and underscores but do not start with a digit or underscore and cannot be a keyword such as class, for, return, global, pass, print, or raise.

Because `namedtuple`s have a dynamic field structure. You give a list of identifiers and it creates a class with related `field`s.

Since it have a dynamic field type, developers tries to avoid as much condition as possible to make `field_names` flexible. They named base class methods with an underscore, (`_make()`, `_replace()`, `_asdict()` and `_fields`) so you can use un-underscored names for field names or like.

No identifier can start with a digit and no class method or property or field may have the name of a `keyword` in python as a general rule. As for the last rule of `namedtuple` `field_name` naming, names that start with an underscore are not available since they are reserved for method and property names of the `namedtuple` class.

Answer (score 9):

`namedtuple` is a bit unusual thing in python. It is not a base class, it is a class generator. Invoking it creates a new class that uses a tuple for its storage and can be manipulated as either tuple or normal class with named fields.

The generated class is intended to be used as a *base* for your own types that will add methods, and constraints. Including constraints that tie the values of individual fields together.

So the namedtuple might be used as base for classes that *don't* support replacing. And since derived class can't remove methods its base provides, the method must not be public.

However some derived classes might want that functionality. So it is provided, as internal method. The subclass can export it if it has a good use for it.

Answer (score 6):

This was apparently done so that the `namedtuple` members (`_replace`, `_fields`, `_field_defaults`, `_make`, and `_asdict`) would not collide with field names (keys, sort of) that users of `namedtuple` might wish to create. It seems it is an unfortunate side effect that this collides with the PEP that you provided. (I got here searching for answers after PyCharm's PEP enforcement flagged my use of `_fields` as "access to a protected member." Irritating, but not a serious issue for me.)

From the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields:

> In addition to the methods inherited from tuples, named tuples support three additional methods and two attributes. To prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore.